# How to convert string to integer in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of directories with numbers. I have to find the highest number and and increment it by 1 and create a new directory with that increment value. I am able to sort the below array, but I am not able to increment the last element as it is a string.

How do I convert this below array element to an integer?

```
PS C:\Users\Suman\Desktop> $FileList

Name
----
11
2
1
```

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can specify the type of a variable before it to force its type. It's called **(dynamic) casting** ([more information is here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)):

```
$string = "1654"
$integer = [int]$string

$string + 1
# Outputs 16541

$integer + 1
# Outputs 1655
```

---

As an example, the following snippet adds, to each object in `$fileList`, an `IntVal` property with the integer value of the `Name` property, then sorts `$fileList` on this new property (the default is ascending), takes the last (highest `IntVal`) object's `IntVal` value, increments it and finally creates a folder named after it:

```
# For testing purposes
#$fileList = @([PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "11" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "2" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "1" })
# OR
#$fileList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
#$fileList.AddRange(@([PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "11" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "2" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "1" })) | Out-Null

$highest = $fileList |
    Select-Object *, @{ n = "IntVal"; e = { [int]($_.Name) } } |
    Sort-Object IntVal |
    Select-Object -Last 1

$newName = $highest.IntVal + 1

New-Item $newName -ItemType Directory
```

`Sort-Object IntVal` is not needed so you can remove it *if you prefer*.

`[int]::MaxValue = 2147483647` so you need to use the `[long]` type beyond this value (`[long]::MaxValue = 9223372036854775807`).

Comment: and if it is a long number use
 [long]"232312333123"

Answer (score 4):

Example:

> 2.032 MB (2,131,022 bytes)

```
$u=($mbox.TotalItemSize.value).tostring()

$u=$u.trimend(" bytes)") #yields 2.032 MB (2,131,022

$u=$u.Split("(") #yields `$u[1]` as 2,131,022

$uI=[int]$u[1]
```

The result is 2131022 in integer form.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$filelist = @(11, 1, 2)
$filelist | sort @{expression={$_[0]}} | 
  % {$newName = [string]([int]$($_[0]) + 1)}
  New-Item $newName -ItemType Directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$filelist = @("11", "1", "2")
$filelist | sort @{expression={[int]$_}} | % {$newName = [string]([int]$_ + 1)}
New-Item $newName -ItemType Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for how this can be run from command line, as a single command, this is one way it can be done:

```
$FileList | ` # Writes array to pipeline
Select-Object -Last 1 | ` # Selects last item in array
ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent "{[int]NameTmp:12}" | ` # Converts string to number and names the variable "NameTmp"
Add-Member -Name "Name" -Value { $this.NameTmp + 1 } -MemberType ScriptProperty -PassThru | ` # Increments variable "NameTmp" by one and adds new variable named "Name" to pipeline object
New-Item -Type Directory # Creates new directy in current folder. Takes directory name from pipelined "Name" variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, PowerShell.  Here is the magic set of syntax to do it with a reasonably simple and comprehensible pipeline:

Starting with

```
$FileList = @([PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "11" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "2" }, [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "1" })
```

This will convert the objects into a sequence of integers:

```
$FileList `
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ` #instead of objects with a 'name' property, just use the name property as the object
  | ForEach-Object { ([int]$_) } #convert each value into an int
```

Given that, you can get the next number by sorting, taking one element, and adding 1 to that element, in a similar fashion (new line added only for clarity)

```
#as above
$FileList `
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ` 
  | ForEach-Object { ([int]$_) } `

  | Sort-Object -Descending ` 
  | Select-Object -First 1 ` #grab only the maximum number
  | ForEach-Object { $_ + 1 }; #increment that maximum to the next number
```

You can further take that pipeline and use it to generate the file name from the number, and probably pipe that into a call to create the file/directory

Answer (score -2):

Once you have selected the highest value, which is "12" in my example, you can then declare it as integer and increment your value:

```
$FileList = "1", "2", "11"
$foldername = [int]$FileList[2] + 1
$foldername
```

Comment: I think OP wants to have the script find the highest value

Comment: Sorry but your answer assumes the array/list always has 3 elements, which is not really flexible.

Comment: ... and creating a directory. Outputting the directory name will not magicly create it : )