# Powershell Do Until Loop

Tags: powershell

```
$StartID = Read-Host -Prompt "StartID"
$StopID = Read-Host -Prompt "StopID"
$i = $StartID
do {
    Write-Host $startID
    Write-Host $StopID
    $i = ($StartId + 1)
} until ($i -gt $StopID)
```

The first problem is that after the statement `$i = $startid + 1`, the `$i` equals 11 and not 2.
The second problem is that even though the until statement says that it should stop when `$i -gt $stop` the loop continues forever.

How do I get the `$i` to increase by 1 and not 10 and how do I stop the loop when `$i -gt $stop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Read-Prompt`returns a string per default (this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707193/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-powershell) explains different ways for conversion). You've to convert/cast the string to a numeric value:

```
[int]$start = Read-Host -Prompt "Start"
[int]$stop = Read-Host -Prompt "Stop"

do {
   Write-host $start
   $start++
} until ($start -ge $stop)
```

Hope that helps.